# Calculating cumulative sum of an equation

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frame `dat` in R:

```
a <- c(6,6,6,7,9,10,11,13,16,17,19,20,22,10,23,25,32,32,34,35,6)
b <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)
q <- c(3,2,4,2,4,2,2,3,0,5,0,6,1,0,3,4,9,1,2,0,12)

dat <- data.frame(a, b, q)
dat <- dat[order(dat$a),]
```

For each level of `a`, I have to compute  `f = with(dat, sum(q[a==that level]*b[a==that level])/sum(b[a==that level]))`. For example, for `a=6`, the  `f=(3*1+2*1+4*0+12*1)/(3+2+4+12)=17/21`.

So I have written the codes as following:

```
dat$qb <- dat$q * dat$b

v1 <- as.numeric(by(dat$qb, dat$a, FUN=sum))
dat$sqb <- rep(v1, table(dat$a))

v2<-as.numeric(by(dat$q, dat$a, FUN=sum))
dat$sumq <- rep(v2, table(dat$a))

dat$f <- dat$sqb/dat$sumq
```

Now I need only the columns `a` and `f`:

```
dat <- unique(dat[,c(1,7)])
```

My next step is to calculate the cumulative sum of the equation `f = with(dat, sum(q[a==that level]*b[a==that level])/sum(b[a==that level]))`:

```
dat <- replace(dat, is.na(dat), 0)
dat$F <- cumsum(dat$f)
```

Ultimately, I need the maximum value of `F` for which `a<=18`:

```
Ft <- max(dat$F[dat$a<=18])
```

This is a part of a simulation and this part target is to find the value of `Ft <- max(dat$F[dat$a<=18])`. I think there is faster way to write these chunk of codes.

- Any faster chunk of R codes to calculate `Ft` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` to group by 'a', calculate 'f' by multiplying 'b' with 'q', get the `sum` and divide by the `sum` of 'q'.  Create 'F' as the `cumsum` of 'f' after `replace`ing NA with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- dat %>%
          group_by(a) %>% 
          summarise(f = sum(b*q)/sum(q)) %>%
          mutate(F = cumsum(replace(f, is.na(f), 0)))
```

Filter the rows where 'a' is less than or equal to 18, extract the 'F' column and get the `max`

```
dat1 %>%
     filter(a <= 18) %>%
     .$F %>%
     max
#[1] 3.809524
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(f= sum(b*q)/sum(q)) , a][is.na(f), f := 0
            ][, F := cumsum(f)][a <= 18, max(F)]
#[1] 3.809524
```